# Prevent button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery for min and maxlength. I want here to prevent button if minlength is not correct. I mean if user not entered minimum 8 digit, then prevent button.

jQuery:

```
var minLength = '8';
var maxLength = '13';
$("input[name=354]").keypress(function(){
    if(this.value.length > maxLength) {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, maxLength);
    }
    if(this.value.length < minLength) {
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #f00');
    } else {
        $(this).css('border-color','#cfdadd');
    }
});
```

HTML button code:

`<button type="button" class="btn next">Next</button>`

Comment: Your actual button can't submit anything : it isn't either a `type=submit` or written in js that it has to submit

Comment: Why you don't use `minLength` and `maxLength` attribute in your input to validating value?

Comment: @tektiv Yes right, it will not submit anything, button will just move to the next slide. I just have to prevent this button not to move to next slide, without proper validation.

Comment: @Mohammad Because `minLength` and `maxLength` was not working, don't know why. I tried this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `disabled` attribute to button if length of input isn't valid.

```js
var minLength = "5";
var maxLength = "10";
$("input").on("keydown change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    // length is short
    if (minLength > value.length){
        $("button").attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).addClass("error");  
    } else {
        $("button").attr("disabled", false);
        $(this).removeClass("error");  
    }
    
    // length is long
    if (value.length > maxLength)
        this.value = value.slice(0, maxLength);    
});
```

```css
.error {
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.48);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px -1px red;  
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="number" class="error" />
    <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just for my knowledge, why «keydown keyup change» ? Looks overkill! The function runs twice on each user's key hit AND on change.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette `keydown` and `change` event is necessary. `keydown` event to entering text using keyboard and `change` event to entering text using mouse (copy and paste text using mouse).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `disabled`.

And it would be better to use `input` instead of `keypress`.

```js
var minLength = '8';
var maxLength = '13';

$('input[name=354]').on('input', function() {
  if (this.value.length > maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, maxLength);
  }
  if (this.value.length < minLength) {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
     $(this).addClass('invalid');
    }
    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
   $(this).removeClass('invalid');
    $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="invalid" name="354" type="text">
<button type="button" class="btn next" disabled>Next</button>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7wuzacx/)